# Batch - I would like to search with a variable in one file and replace that variable result in another file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I would like to search using a variable in one file, then take that variable result and replace part of some text in another file.

For exmaple in "1.txt" I have a text line of:
ClassName=X

X changes within the file depending on the line of text that you search ClassName= So I would have to search using  a variable with ClassName=

I would then search for X in another file after the word "Class=", replacing it with the word "ShipDummy". We'll call the second file "2.txt". X within the second file would be found like this: Class=X. However, I would like it to be Class=ShipDummy

I would search similar to the layout in 1.txt, but without the "Name" part, and 1.txt wont get ShipDummy either.

I would also like to make a backup of 2.txt before the replacement takes place.

Also, there are many ClassName= lines in 1.txt, all with different x values. I'd like it to give a variable for each x value, then doing the replace for that value in 2.txt. For example:
ClassName=x in 1.txt (replace Class=x in 2.txt with Class=ShipDummy)

ClassName=y in 1.txt (replace Class=y in 2.txt with Class=ShipDummy)

ClassName=z in 1.txt (replace Class=z in 2.txt with Class=ShipDummy)

and so on....

Keep in mind, in the above I am using x, y and z as variables here.

How would I do all this? I am new to coding and its quite complex. I'd like this in a batch file.

What I have is something like this, but I'm lost:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (1.txt) do 

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%A in ("!var2!") do echo !var1:Name=%%A!

exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to solve this is to approach it from the reverse direction.

Read each line in in 2.txt. If the line matches the templpate `Class=X`, then parse out X and search to see if `ClassName=X` exists in 1.txt. If it does exist, then write the replacement line, else write the original line.

You can search for a string within a file using FINDSTR. You don't care about the output, so output is redirected to null. The `&&` operator conditionally executes code if the prior command (FINDSTR) was successful (matched).

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>2.txt.new (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in (2.txt) do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    if "!ln:~0,6!" == "Class=" findstr /c:"ClassName=!ln:~6!" 1.txt >null && set "ln=Class=ShipDummy"
    echo !ln!
  )
)
move 2.txt.new 2.txt
```

The script above is untested, but the concept should work. There is lots of room for improvement.

Comment: Actually, just one bit. If 1.txt has: ClassName=x then ClassName=y and then ClassName=x again, the batch will only replace the first Class=x in the 2.txt file, and then move on to the Class=y. I would like it to process the x all the way through the 2.txt file first, then process the y, then z, etc...  Is that possible?

Comment: I'm sorry I said that backwards. If an instance of x comes before And after y in 2.txt, only the first x will get changed to ShipDummy. 2.txt will have multiple instances of x. 1.txt will only have 1 instance of x, 1 of y, 1 of x, etc...

Comment: Essentially what I"m saying is, how to I repeat that ShipDummy function in 2.txt, to ensure all Class=x are Class=ShipDummy?