# Search filename with variable and replace different variable text in another file with multiple lines

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I had an answer to my question previously, but now I've realised that i need a bit more help. I have code that does almost everything I want it to:

```
@echo off

copy 2.txt 2.txt-backup

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

>2.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in (2.txt-backup) do (
 set "ln=%%A"
if "!ln:~0,6!" == "Class=" findstr /c:"ClassName=!ln:~6!" 1.txt >null && set       "ln=Class=ShipDummy"
echo !ln!
 )
)
```

Please refer to this:
[Batch - I would like to search with a variable in one file and replace that variable result in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992029/batch-i-would-like-to-search-with-a-variable-in-one-file-and-replace-that-vari)

But now I've realized I need 1.txt to be a file name with a variable in its name, a series of files, with no exact limit like:

Log_0.txt

Log_1.txt

Log_2.txt

Log_3.txt

and so on....

There may be just Log_0.txt, or there may be Log_0.txt through Log_23.txt, or even more...

Also, I'd like to add another line to the replacement text of Class=ShipDummy to be:
Class-ShipDummy
Type=206

And that would replace a line of text just below Class=ShipDummy replacement text with Type=206.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
@echo off

copy 2.txt 2.txt-backup

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

>2.txt (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" 2.txt-backup') do (
        ( echo !ln!| findstr "^Type=206$" >NUL && set ln=ln ) || (
            set "ln=%%B"
            if "!ln:~0,6!"=="Class=" (
                findstr /c:"ClassName=!ln:~6!" Log_*.txt >null && (
                    echo Class=ShipDummy
                    set "ln=Type=206"
                )
            )
            if #!ln!==# (echo;) else echo !ln!
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Almost. It changes everything as you said, but I would like to replace the line below Class=ShipDummy with Type=206, this one just adds Type=206 below it moving everything else down one line. Also, it combines all the lines within the file, stacking them all up one after the other removing the blank lines. How can how do this without removing blank lines?

Comment: There, I made a change that'll replace the next line rather than insert.  As far as keeping the whitespace, I might have to let that for the next person to figure out.  I'm out for the day.  :)

Comment: I'm getting close, something like this so it doesn't remove blank lines: @echo off

copy 2.txt 2.txt-backup

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

>2.txt (
    for /f "delims=" %%A in (2.txt-backup ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
        ( echo !ln!| findstr "^Type=206$" >NUL && (
            set ln=ln
        ) ) || (
            set "ln=%%A"
            if "!ln:~0,6!"=="Class=" (
                findstr /c:"ClassName=!ln:~6!" Log_*.txt >null && (
                    echo Class=ShipDummy
                    set "ln=Type=206"
                )
            )
            echo !ln!
        )
    )
)

Comment: Good idea.  I added line numbering to `findstr` and skipped it with `"tokens=1*"` capturing `%%B`.  See if this works for you now.